# Include DB output from a file in an class

Tags: php, arrays, class

I'm trying to edit an class with an DB driven result.
I use ColorInterpreter by Our Code World, which is a PHP port of the JavaScript library NTC JS.

In this class is a public variable which is a array of hex/colorname pairs. This is hardcoded into the class. I want to make this dynamic with the use of an DB output.

I'm still struggeling with classes so I can't get my head around this.

**colornames.inc.php**:
Outputs something like this:

```
Array
(
    [b0bf1a] => Acid Green
    [7cb9e8] => Aero
    [c9ffe5] => Aero Blue
    [b284be] => African Violet
    [00308f] => Air Force Blue (USAF)
    [72a0c1] => Air superiority Blue
    ...
}
```

**ColorInterpreter.php**:

```
class ColorInterpreter
    {
        public function __construct()
            {
                $color =            null;
                $rgb =              null;
                $hsl =              null;
                $name =             null;

                for($i = 0; $i < count($this->names); $i++)
                    {
                        $color =    "#".$this->names[$i][0];
                        $rgb =      $this->rgb($color);
                        $hsl =      $this->hsl($color);

                        array_push
                            (
                                $this->names[$i],
                                $rgb[0],
                                $rgb[1],
                                $rgb[2],
                                $hsl[0],
                                $hsl[1],
                                $hsl[2]
                            );
                    }
            }


        public function name($color)
            {
                ...
            }

        // adopted from: Farbtastic 1.2
        // http://acko.net/dev/farbtastic
        public function hsl($color)
            {
                ...
            }

        // adopted from: Farbtastic 1.2
        // http://acko.net/dev/farbtastic
        public function rgb($color)
            {
                ...
            }


        public function color($name)
            {
                ...
            }

// Below is the part I need to replace with the output given from colornames.inc.php
    public $names = array(
// Pink colors
array("FFC0CB", "Pink"),
array("FFB6C1", "Light Pink"),
array("FF69B4", "Hot Pink"),
array("FF1493", "Deep Pink"),
array("DB7093", "Pale Violet Red"),
array("C71585", "Medium Violet Red"),

array("E0115F", "Ruby"),
array("FF6FFF", "Ultra"),
...
    );

    }
```

I don't know how, if or where I could/should include the colornames.inc.php
And I don't know where to correctly declare the needed variables. Obviously, $this->names represent the hardcoded array, but how has this to be changed to reflect the DB output I have?
I'm completely lost here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to create a function that returns the values, and then pass that as the constructor when you create the class. e.g.

```
include 'file_with_function.php';
include 'file_with_class.php';

$initialColorValues = my_get_color_values();
$newObject = new ColorObject($initialColorValues);
```

Now you can process that array in the constructor, and you have an object that is seeded with the correct color values

```
class XYZ {
    public $names;
    public function __construct($names){
       // ... do work
       $this->names = $work;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. But how does this "overwrite" the public $names / $this->names variable in the class?

Comment: You will need to code that logic into your constructor so the class accepts the values and then populated the values.

Comment: Yes ... but that's exactly my problem. As I wrote above, I can't figure out how to implement this.
Maybe you could help me out and point me in the right direction ... ?

Comment: Take a look at the example I just put up there. That would be how you would accept the value and then assign it into the class.

Comment: Ah, now this makes sense! Many thanks! I could implment it and after setting $this->names = $names; and editing the array output, it finally works.